# How to run initialization code only once when the Remix server starts?

Tags: typescript, remix.run

I'm using Remix and I have some initialization code that I'd like to run when the Remix server starts. I've put my code in `entry.server.tsx` but I realized that this runs on every request. Is there a specific remix file or callback where I can put that I intend to run **only once** during the lifecycle of the app (at the start)?

I'm using the default settings (default Remix server).

Answer (score 0):

In development, Remix will purge the require cache on every request. If you have global data that needs to survive the purge, like database connections, etc., you'll need to store this reference on the `global` object.

Here's a helper function and example to do that:

```js
// utils/singleton.server.ts

// since the dev server re-requires the bundle, do some shenanigans to make
// certain things persist across that 
// Borrowed/modified from https://github.com/jenseng/abuse-the-platform/blob/2993a7e846c95ace693ce61626fa072174c8d9c7/app/utils/singleton.ts

export function singleton<Value>(name: string, value: () => Value): Value {
    const yolo = global as any
    yolo.__singletons ??= {}
    yolo.__singletons[name] ??= value()
    return yolo.__singletons[name]
}
```

```js
// utils/prisma.server.ts

import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'
import { singleton } from './singleton.server.ts'

const prisma = singleton('prisma', () => new PrismaClient())
prisma.$connect()

export { prisma }
```